# Improve error handling of the code

Tags: java, security, try-catch

I want to improve some security aspects of my code.  If there is any error while executing `alg.solve()`, then the process should not be stopped, rather the `null` must be returned by `runMethod()`. Will the following code snippet work this way?

```
   public Result runMethod() 
    {
      Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(this);
      Result r = null;
      try
      {
         r = alg.solve();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return r;
    }
```

Comment: (If you are going to return `null`, I'd write the body a bit more explicitly and concisely. `Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(this); try { return alg.solve(); } catch (SomeException exc) { return null; }`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Some comments:

1. Don't use `e.printStackTrace();`. First of all, it swallows useful information from chained exceptions. Next, you can't control whether it should print or not. Lastly, you can never be sure that there is a `stderr` to print to.

   Use a logging framework instead.
2. Instead of returning `null`, consider defining an exception of your own. That would allow you to include useful information that a user (who doesn't understand any of this) can then report back to you so you have a chance to figure out why the error happened.